# Point cloud Normal based fitering

Tags: filter, ros, point-cloud-library, normals

I am using PCL to estimate the normals of point cloud data. It returns to me a vector with four elements the first three are varying between -1 and 1. How can I cluster the point cloud data according to the normals.

Comment: Is this http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/region_growing_segmentation.php what you're looking for?

Comment: [Euclidean clustering on point cloud data using PCL library](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php)

Comment: Thank you guys , I manged it , it works for me now. I estimated the angles based on atan in c++